# How to require form parameters on the value of another form parameter in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have the following OpenAPI (Swagger) definition for a POST request with form data. How can I vary the required form parameters based on the value of the `type` parameter?

If `type`="email" only the `email` is required and if `type`="phone" only `country` and `phone` parameters are required.

```yaml
  /login:
    post:
      required:
      - type
      - password
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/SomeResponse'
      parameters:
        - name: type
          type: string
          in: formData
          enum: [email, phone]
        - name: email
          type: string
          in: formData
        - name: country
          type: string
          in: formData
        - name: phone
          type: string
          in: formData
        - name: password
          type: string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional dependencies in form data can be expressed in OpenAPI 3, but not in OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: 2.0`).

#### OpenAPI 3.1

This example uses `if..then`, a new construct in OAS 3.1.

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
...

paths:
  /login:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response

components:
  schemas:
    LoginRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - type
        - password
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          enum: [email, phone]
        email:
          type: string
        country:
          type: string
        phone:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string

      # Conditional dependencies
      allOf:
        # If type="email", then the `email` field is required
        - if:
            properties:
              type:
                const: email
          then:
            required: [email]

        # If type="phone", then the `country` and `phone` fields are required
        - if:
            properties:
              type:
                const: phone
          then:
            required: [country, phone]
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x

In OAS 3.0, you can use the following `oneOf` construct to express these conditions.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
...

paths:
  /login: ... # The path definition is the same as in the previous example


components:
  schemas:
    LoginRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - type
        - password
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          enum: [email, phone]
        email:
          type: string
        country:
          type: string
        phone:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string

      # Conditional dependencies
      oneOf:
        # If type="email" ...
        - properties:
            type:
              enum: [email]
          # ... then the `email` field is required
          required: [email]

        # If type="phone" ...
        - properties:
            type:
              enum: [phone]
          # ...then the `country` and `phone` fields are required
          required: [country, phone]
```

#### OpenAPI 2.0

In OpenAPI 2.0, the most you can do is define the conditionally required parameters (`email`, `country` and `phone` in your example) as optional and mention the dependencies in the operation description and/or parameter descriptions.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

paths:
  /login:
    post:
      ...
      parameters:
        - name: type
          type: string
          in: formData
          enum: [email, phone]
          required: true
        - name: email
          type: string
          in: formData
          description: Required if type=email
        - name: country
          type: string
          in: formData
          description:  Required if type=phone
        - name: phone
          type: string
          in: formData
          description:  Required if type=phone
        - name: password
          type: string
          in: formData
          required: true
```

Comment: What if the condition is based on a boolean, not an enum? (OpenAPI 3.0.x)
If type was a bool, what would this section:


```
oneOf:
        # If type="email" ...
        - properties:
            type:
              enum: [email]
```
look like?

Comment: Or simply check if `type != null`